# Jtextfield setText() would not work at all

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jfilechooser

So this is what I'm trying to do is to get the absolutePath into the jtextfield and I did System print and it showed the path but would not set the text in jtextfield.

Action event (button) in wizard class :

```
  //buttons
  JButton openMapButton = new JButton("Load Map");
  ImageLoader imgload = new ImageLoader();
  openMapButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        imgload.fileChooser();
     }
 });
```

Jtextfield in Wizard class:

```
      JTextField mapURLField = new JTextField(20);
```

ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader extends Wizard{

private JLabel label; 
JFileChooser chooser;
File file; 
private BufferedImage img;
Wizard wiz = new Wizard();
JTextField mapURLField;   


public void loadImg(){
}


public void fileChooser(){
 wiz.mapURLField = new JTextField();
      
  if(chooser == null){
  chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
}

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
  wiz.mapURLField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
  System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
  }else{
     wiz.mapURLField.setText("");
  }
  
  chooser.setSelectedFile(null);


 } 
}
```

Comment: So are you saying `System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());` works but `wiz.mapURLField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());` doesn't?  If that is the case does setting the textfield with any value work?

Comment: This, `Wizard wiz = new Wizard();` may be your problem. You're creating a ***new*** Wizard object, but is it the same as the displayed one? Impossible to really say without a decent [mre]. I also have to wonder if you're using inheritance correctly when you do, `ImageLoader extends Wizard`.

Comment: If `ImageLoader extends Wizard` then why are you instantiating a `new Wizard()` - oops repeating @HovercraftFullOfEels comment

Comment: Then there's `wiz.mapURLField = new JTextField();` - which is most certainly *not* the displayed JTextField. You look to be misuing references *throughout* this code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the state of the wrong JTextField inside of the *wrong* Wizard object. The text field that should be changed is the one that is displayed in the ***displayed*** Wizard class, not a JTextField that you create on the spot in some other class that is in a newly created non-displayed Wizard class that you also create in your ImageLoader.

This:

```
public class ImageLoader extends Wizard{
    private JLabel label; 

    // ....        

    Wizard wiz = new Wizard();
    JTextField mapURLField;
```

creates a ***new*** Wizard object, but it is certainly *not* the Wizard object that is currently being displayed, and so changing the state of this newly created and non-displayed object will not help you.

Instead, change:

```
ImageLoader imgload = new ImageLoader();
```

to:

```
ImageLoader imgload = new ImageLoader(this);
```

if not called within an ActionListener or other anonymous class, as this should load the displayed Wizard object into the ImageLoader class.

And in ImageLoader do:

```
private Wizard wiz; // a field to hold the displayed Wizard

public ImageLoader(Wizard wiz) {
    this.wiz = wiz; // set the field with the parameter passed in
    ....
}
```

and then call the methods of *true Wizard object, now held by wiz, in your ImageLoader class.

Also, get rid of

```
wiz.mapURLField = new JTextField();
```

It makes no sense creating a *new* JTextField, one that certainly is not being displayed in the original Wizard object. You want to change the state of the displayed JTextField. The best way to do this is to give Wizard a public method that allows you to do this:

```
// in the Wizard class:

public void setMapUrlField(String text) {
    mapURLField.setText(text);
}
```

---

Finally, the ImageLoader extending the Wizard class:

```
public class ImageLoader extends Wizard {
```

is probably not doing what you think it's doing, and is likely not what you want to be doing.

---

Proof of concept code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Wizard extends JPanel {
    private ImageLoader imgload = new ImageLoader(this);
    private JTextField mapURLField = new JTextField(30);
    private JButton openMapButton = new JButton("Load Map");
    private File file;
    
    public Wizard() {
        openMapButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            file = imgload.fileChooser();
        });
        
        mapURLField.setFocusable(false);
        add(mapURLField);
        add(openMapButton);
    }
    
    public void setMapUrlField(String text) {
        mapURLField.setText(text);
    } 
    
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Wizard wiz = new Wizard();
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wizard");
            frame.add(wiz);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
class ImageLoader {

    private Wizard wiz;

    public ImageLoader(Wizard wizard) {
        this.wiz = wizard;
    }

    public File fileChooser() {
        File file = null;
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int retValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(wiz);
        if (retValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            wiz.setMapUrlField(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            wiz.setMapUrlField("");
        }
        
        return file;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and it helped me to understand more clearly. It worked but there's one small issue and I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTextField.setText(String)" because "this.mapURLField"` is null but when I debugged it, it's clearly not null since it showed the url?

I thought extending would give the class access to the method and whatnot but I was wrong.

Comment: Never mind, apparently it's because I had 2 "new jtextfield" one was just for naming and one was for creating. What would be the correct way to do this? ( like `private JTextField siteNameField, aisleNumField, laneNumField;` and `JTextField siteNameField = new JTextField(5); .....)`

Comment: @Zyaan: You declare your Swing components that need to interact with outside objects as private fields of the class and use public methods to allow controlled interactions as I have shown in my code here. If this doesn't answer your question that you've asked above, then I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't ask correctly but I mean like what's the easiest way to declare more than 1 jtextfields without having to do `"JTextfields jt = new JTextField(20);` for each jtextfield variable instead of having one declaration AND another one to create it in the body like I did?

and I also wanted to say thank you again for helping me with my problem :)